# ChangeConflictException in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I receive "Row not found or changed exception".

```
System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed. at
System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) at
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

How I to tell what column causes the exception?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your linq source please?

Answer (score 2):

See [How to: Retrieve Member Conflict Information (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386985.aspx) if you just want code a code example.

By default in Linq2Sql, every property is included in the optimistic concurrency check. You can customize this behavior by setting the `UpdateCheck` property of the `Column` attribute in your Linq2Sql class to `Always` (the default), `Never`, or `WhenChanged` to only include a column in the concurrency check if its value changed. It's covered in greater detail on MSDN: [Optimistic Concurrency Overview (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373.aspx)